# How do I disable a textfield?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, keyboard, textfield

I have a textfield which displays a result but I don't want it to be accessible by the user as in I don't want the keyboard to come up. How would I go about that in text?

Comment: Why don’t you display the result in a label?

Comment: Zoul makes a good point. Text fields are for user input. Labels are more appropriate for displaying non-editable text.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe you are looking for: `UITextField.enabled = NO;` or
`UITextField.hidden = YES;`

:)
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

`UITextField.enabled` rather than `UITextField.Hidden`, otherwise you will no longer see your textfield.

Comment: I included the "hidden" attribute for completeness' sake :)